# Ansible xml manipulation similar to lineinfile

Tags: xml, xpath, replace, ansible

In Ansible, I'm looking for a technique that works similar to `lineinfile` or `replace` but for XML files when using templates is not an option. Seems like a very common need.

With XML files, though, it is necessary to specify an `xpath` to guarantee the element is present/absent from the correct place in the DOM.

The solution needs to ensure there is a mechanism of replacing an existing node that *could* look quite a bit different than the target node.

Trivial example XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<datasources-configuration xmlns:myns="http://org.someorg.ds/config">
  <datasources>
    <!-- various other xml -->
    <datasource>
        <name>MyDS</name>
        <jdbcUrl>...</jdbcUrl>
    </datasource>
  </datasources>
  <!-- various other xml -->
</datasources-configuration>
```

I want to be able to ensure a full multiline block of XML gets inserted/replaced into target XML file given a certain xpath expression is matched. For example, to add the following datasource to datasources:

```
   <datasource>
      <name>AnotherDS</name>
      <jdbcUrl>...</jdbcUrl>
   </datasource>
```

The best that I've seen is this custom module which breaks on it's own examples: https://github.com/cmprescott/ansible-xml

Does such a module exist or solution recommendations?

Comment: Why are templates not an option? Your example looks templateable to me.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR This file has already been templated by a separate, independent baseline provision. Templating by newer, incremental playbooks and roles would blow away the baseline.

Comment: You seem to be missing the point of templating if it's not creating an output file exactly how you want for the environment. Can you share what you are doing in the templating play? ie the play, the j2 template and any necessary inventory variables.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR the baseline provisions a known configuration at the time. later playbooks need to add, delete or modify _partial_ segments without having to know the full contents of the file. Think of a tomcat install, you don't know all your datasources when you first configure it. At the same time, a later role should not be concerned about the entire file which is exactly what a template would require. There is, after all, a reason why you have linefile and replace, for exact cases when you don't know or care about unrelated sections. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: You could use command to run the template through an xslt, passing in certain things as params to the xslt. For something lighter, but still xml-aware, check out the utility xmlstarlet: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLStarlet

Comment: Good tip, once sourceforge comes up, I will give it a try. Thanks @David

Comment: @MikeD You can install xmlstarlet from apt-get or brew. I generally avoid visiting sourceforge :-)

Comment: @David brew installs it from sourceforge but I know what you mean.

Answer (score 9):

I was just looking into this myself and discovered an [ansible-xml](https://github.com/cmprescott/ansible-xml) module that looks like a great option.

Comment: Yes, I pointed this out in my question. That code fails on its own examples. If you have better luck, please share your experience.

Comment: What examples is it breaking on? I'm the maintainer of that repo. Is it one of the outstanding issues?

Comment: all the issues are in the issues section on the github :)

Comment: see below, its XML module is now officially part of the Ansible distribution

Answer (score 7):

Update for current users. Since Ansible 2.4 there is an official XML module
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/xml_module.html